# Loading and reprojecting .nc file without projection

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis, gdalwarp, netcdf

I am trying to extract some bands from a `.nc` file. I don't know the file projection (if there is one), thus I created in GRASS GIS a `newLocation` with no projection (just a XY Cartesian plane) and tried to loaded the specific subset of the `.nc` I'm interested in.
The file is `states.nc`, available here: https://luh.umd.edu/data.shtml specifically, LUH2 v2h Release 10/14/16.
These are, for instance, the information of one subset of `states.nc`

```
gdalinfo NETCDF:"/myPath/states.nc":primf
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: /myPath/states.nc
Size is 1440, 720
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
```

I am working at European level, thus at this point I switch to my location with `EPSG:3035` projection and set my computational region (to a raster map of Europe, `EU_3035`) and resolution (1000 meters).
I want to create a mask of the European raster I have and load (while reprojecting in `EPSG:3035`) each raster band I obtained from `states.nc` (using Europe as a mask).

```
for band in 1121 1122 1123 1124 1125 1126 1127 1128 1129 1130 1131 1132 1133 1134 1135 1136 1137 1138 1139 1140 1141 1142 1143 1144 1145 1146 1147 1148 1149 1150 1151 1152 1153 1154 1155 1156 1157 1158 1159 1160 1161 1162 1163 1164 1165 1166;
do
echo "CREATE A MASK OF EU, CROP AND REPROJECT BAND $band TO LAEA3035"
r.mask --o raster=EU_3035
r.proj --o location=newLocation mapset=PERMANENT input='pastr.'$band output='pastr.'$band'_3035'
r.mask -r
done
```

At this point, I get an error message:

```
WARNING: <PROJ_INFO> file not found for location <newLocation>
ERROR: Unable to get projection info of input map
```

I can see on my file browser some files I usually have in my other locations (e.g., `PROJ_INFO`, `PROJ_UNITS`) are missing. I cannot frame the exact problem and I am not sure if my workflow, so far, is correct.

I tried another approach with `gdalwarp` (that I used in the past to solve another projection problem). I first reproject the rasters I loaded from `newLocation` to `WGS84`.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0' -tr 0.01 0.01 /myPath/myRaster.tif /myPath/myRaster_WGS84.tif -overwrite
```

I switch to my `WGS84` location and load the files. Then if I check them with `r.info` and `r.stats -c`, I realize they are empty.

```
> r.info map=myRaster_WGS84
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      myRaster_WGS84                 Date: Fri Aug 12 17:14:28 2022    |
 | Mapset:   PERMANENT                      Login of Creator: lisa            |
 | Location: WGS84                                                            |
 | DataBase: /myPath                                                          |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    FCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         100                                                        |
 |   Columns:      100                                                        |
 |   Total Cells:  10000                                                      |
 |        Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                      |
 |            N:         1N    S:          0   Res: 0:00:36                   |
 |            E:         1E    W:          0   Res: 0:00:36                   |
 |   Range of data:    min = NULL  max = NULL                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.in.gdal                                                  |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    r.in.gdal --overwrite input="/myPath/myRaster_WGS84.tif" \              |
 |    output="myRaster_WGS84" memory=300 offset=0 num_digits=0                |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I guess it has to do with the XY location I created, but I don't know which is the appropriate projection and I cannot find this information. Searching on the internet I couldn't find a way to properly load and reproject bands of a .nc file I'm interested in.
I am quite new to GRASS GIS and this is the first .nc file I manage. I am using GRASS 7.8.6 on a server running Ubuntu 18.04.6 from a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to work with that data. Following the hint in your question:

First with `gdalinfo` I found one of the variables, as you did. then I did the transform to WGS84 and clipped to the bounds of Europe along the way:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 0.5 0.5 -te 0 30 40 50 NETCDF:"states.nc":primf primf_WGS84.tif -overwrite
```

I chose a lower resolution (0.5 degrees) than what you want, to save some space. But the data itself is, I believe, only at 0.25 degrees anyway.

Then I started GRASS in a WGS84 defined location and did:

```
r.external primf_WGS84.tif output=primf
```

and I got 1000 Forest primary production maps.

Comment: Thanks @Micha. I tried two different approaches (one's yours) that led to two slightly different results, as you can see in my self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I tried two different approaches (example here with `pastr` subset and bands `1165` and `1166`).

1. First approach

I assumed `states.nc` was in `WGS84`. I first loaded the `pastr` bands I was interested in into my `WGS84` location (note the `-o` flag to override projection check):

```
for band in 1165 1166;
do
r.in.gdal --o -o input=NETCDF:"/myPath/states.nc":pastr band=$band
output='pastr_WGS84_'$band 
done
```

I switch to my EPSG:3035 location, set computational region (EU_3035) and resolution (1000 meters). I then reproject and cut the rasters to Europe:

```
for band in 1165 1166;
do
r.mask --o raster=EU_3035
r.proj --o location=WGS84 mapset=PERMANENT input='pastr_WGS84_'$band output='pastr_3035_'$band 
r.mask -r
done
```

I average (measures I'm interested in) the rasters:

```
r.series --o input=`g.list type=raster pattern=pastr_3035_* mapset=. separator=,` output=pastrAvg_3035 method=average
```

2. Second approach (based on Micha's answer)

In my `WGS84` location, I reproject `pastr` from the unknown projection to `WGS84` (but without directly clipping to EU):

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 0.5 0.5 NETCDF:"/myPath/states.nc":pastr /myPath/pastr_WGS84.tif -overwrite
```

I load `pastr_WGS84` into `WGS84` location selecting only the bands I was interested in (with `band`):

```
for band in 1165 1166
do
r.in.gdal --o input=/myPath/pastr_WGS84.tif 
output='pastr_WGS84_'$band band=$band
done
```

I switch to `EPSG:3035` location, set computational region (`EU_3035`) and resolution (1000 meters). I import-reproject-clip the raster to Europe and average it, as in the first approach.

The two approaches led to slightly different `pastrAvg_3035` rasters (if I look at the results of `r.univar -e`), in terms of non null cells and median values. I guess it depends from the approach but I cannot exactly understand why, and which one may be more correct (I guess the second - Micha's - approach).

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but be aware that your WGS84 location assumes units are degrees. However the pixel size in the states.nc are 0.25 degrees. So when you transform to EPSG:3035, it's "looking" at a different set of pixels for the interpolation.